# Cassandra import JSON in one column

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch, cassandra

I'm trying to import JSON File in Cassandra in one Column. I'm using Python as code. The idea is to have one id Column and the second Column to be JSON, as it is.

```
id | JSONDoc
----------------
1  | {'something': 'something', 'something1': '['somethingelse': 
'withsomethin']', ...'
```

I'm getting this error when i try to run the following

```
code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Invalid map literal for testdoc 
of type list<text>
```

The code:

```
session.execute("CREATE KEYSPACE doc WITH replication = 
{'class':'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 3};")
session.set_keyspace('doc')
testdoc = str(doc)
session.execute("CREATE TABLE doc4 (nodeid int PRIMARY KEY, testdoc 
list<text>);")
query = "INSERT INTO doc.doc4 (nodeid, testdoc) VALUES ({0}, 
{1})".format(nodeid, testdoc)
session.execute(query)
```

I think im missing something when i creating the table or size of the column where the json is. But i don't know any other way to import it this JSON as it is. Any other suggestions or ways to fix this or import any kind of JSON in one Column?

After that i need to use this JSON in ES. So it will be best if i can import this as JSON in one Column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to pass parameter to CQL, see this doc.
https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/getting_started.html#passing-parameters-to-cql-queries

Try something like this:

```
session.execute("CREATE KEYSPACE doc WITH replication =  {'class':'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1};")

session.set_keyspace('doc')

session.execute("CREATE TABLE doc4 (nodeid int PRIMARY KEY, testdoc text);")

myid = 1

doc = {"id": 101010, "name": "Adriano Bonacin"}

testdoc= str(doc)

session.execute(
"""
INSERT INTO doc.doc4 (nodeid, testdoc)
VALUES (%s, %s)
""",
(myid, testdoc)
)
```

See:

```
cqlsh:doc> select * from doc.doc4;

nodeid | testdoc
--------+-------------------------------------------
  1 | {'id': 101010, 'name': 'Adriano Bonacin'}
```

Comment: Yup this way is working, but the problem is that the in this way its storing it as text. It works but the type is text. And than i have to re index and mapping the whole structure for ES to work. Also, (it has nothing to do with this question), but im getting an error when i work with cluster: "Cannot achieve consistency level LOCAL_ONE".

Answer (score -1):

For the below format how to store json data into cassandra db.

```
{
  "languages": {                  value as dict
    "python": "Elite", 
    "pascal": "Lame", 
    "perl": "Elite"
  }, 
  "foods": [                       value as list
    "Apple", 
    "Orange", 
    "Strawberry", 
    "Mango"
  ], 
  "name": "Martin D'vloper", 
  "employed": "true", 
  "skill": "Elite", 
  "job": "Developer"
}
```